# Order of execution after an event is fired

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, event-handling

```
someClass = Ext.extend(someOtherClass,
   initComponent: function (){
      someFunction();
      this.on('exampleEvent', someFuntion2(), this);
   },
   someFunction: function (){
      this.fireEvent('exampleEvent');
      return null;
   }
   //...
}
```

Immediately after "this.fireEvent('exampleEvent');" does "return null" get executed or "someFuntion2()"? Why?

Comment: If  `someFunction2` does not return a function, the line should probably be `this.on('exampleEvent', someFuntion2, this);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the second argument here:

```
this.on('exampleEvent', someFuntion2(), this);
```

should be a Function object, and you have actually executed someFunction2() here... so you probably meant to say:

```
this.on('exampleEvent', someFuntion2, this);
```

(Notice the missing parens () after someFunction2)

To answer your question, someFunction2 will get executed first, because of the way Observable works in ExtJS.  When you call fireEvent('exampleEvent')... the Observable class (which someClass must extend from at somePoint in the inheritance chain) will loop through all objects that have added a listener for that event, and call the Function object that was passed in when the listener was added -- in your case, someFunction2 (without the parens)

Of course, it is possible to add options when adding the event listener that will cause your function to be executed after a delay when the event is fired...